# PWA nuxt 2 camera problems

Tags: ios, iphone, vuejs2, nuxt.js, progressive-web-apps

(PWA nuxt 2) When I open the camera on the iPhone X ios 16, the app in the background seems to reload and as a result the photographed image does not load. This situation does not occur in the browser, only in PWA.

I don't know how to solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some code and explain what you have tried?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.